# Stripe - Uncaught (in promise) IntegrationError: Invalid value for stripe.confirmCardPayment

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, heroku, stripe-payments

**Console Error message:** `v3:1 Uncaught (in promise) IntegrationError: Invalid value for stripe.confirmCardPayment intent secret: value should be a client secret of the form ${id}_secret_${secret}. You specified: .`

**You can see the error yourself here:** https://stormy-forest-38471.herokuapp.com/

**Instructions to get error:** From the main page, click on `Menú Diari` -> `Demanar` -> Any of the first 3 buttons -> Select one radio button from each category and then click on `Afegeix i paga` -> `Pagar` -> 1st input: 'Random Name', 2nd input: 'Recollida a tenda - Cabrera de Mar', 4th input: '123'...

Then, according to Stripe documentation, you could fill the payment element with the following data in order to achieve a successfull test payment.

**Visa Number:** '4242 4242 4242 4242'

**MM/AA:** '04/24'

**CVC:** '123'

Once you press `Pagar`, you will get the `IntegrationError` I'm asking for in the console.

I am trying to deploy a **React.js + Node.js + Express** web using Heroku.

I have been following this guide, although I am not sure if that's what I need.
https://blog.heroku.com/deploying-react-with-zero-configuration

The web is for a restaurant. They want to sell different lunch plans. I am trying to implement the payment using **Stripe**. When I test the app in my localhost, everything works fine. However, when I try to deploy it, something breaks.

I guess something must be wrong with my `server.js` or `package.json` files... The main problem being that I am a complete noob at Back End...

Everything works as expected (I still have some console logs here and there for development), until I start making requests to the server.

This is my **server.js**

```
const { createServer } = require('https');
const express = require('express');
const compression = require('compression');
const morgan = require('morgan');
const path = require('path');

const normalizePort = (port) => parseInt(port, 10);
const PORT = normalizePort(process.env.PORT || 5000);

const app = express();
const dev = app.get('env') !== 'production';

if (!dev) {
    app.disable('x-powered-by');
    app.use(compression()); // "Will handle a few things for us... (?)"
    app.use(morgan('common'));

    app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));

    app.get('*', (req, res) => {
        res.sendFile(path.resolve(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
    });
}

const server = createServer(app);

const { resolve } = require('path');

const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

app.use(express.json());

const calculateOrderAmount = (items) => {
    console.log(items);
    let drinksTotal = 0;
    const { water, cola, colaZero, beer, lemonFanta, orangeFanta } = items.drinks;
    drinksTotal += water * 100;
    drinksTotal += (cola + colaZero + lemonFanta + orangeFanta) * 130;
    drinksTotal += beer * 150;

    let foodTotal = 0;
    foodTotal += items.primerSegonCount * 895;
    foodTotal += items.dosPrimersCount * 795;
    foodTotal += items.platPostresCount * 695;

    grandTotal = parseInt(drinksTotal + foodTotal);

    console.log(grandTotal);

    return grandTotal;
};

app.post('/create-payment-intent', async(req, res) => {
    const { items } = req.body;
    console.log(items);
    // Create a PaymentIntent with the order amount and currency
    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
        amount: calculateOrderAmount(items),
        currency: 'eur'
    });
    res.send({
        clientSecret: '123_secret_123' //paymentIntent.client_secret
    });
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

server.listen(PORT, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;

    console.log('Server started on port ' + PORT);
});
```

This is my package.json

```
{
    "name": "my-app",
    "version": "0.1.0",
    "private": true,
    "engine": {
        "node": "12.16.3",
        "npm": "6.14.5"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.1.2",
        "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.7.0",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
        "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
        "axios": "^0.19.2",
        "boostrap": "^2.0.0",
        "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
        "compression": "^1.7.4",
        "concurrently": "^5.2.0",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
        "emailjs-com": "^2.4.1",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "morgan": "^1.10.0",
        "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
        "react": "^16.13.1",
        "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.1",
        "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
        "react-redux": "^7.2.0",
        "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
        "react-scroll": "^1.7.16",
        "react-stripe-checkout": "^2.6.3",
        "reactstrap": "^8.5.1",
        "stripe": "^8.67.0",
        "uuid": "^8.2.0",
        "uuidv4": "^6.1.1"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "react-scripts start",
        "start-dev": "nodemon server.js",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject",
        "dev": "concurrently \"npm run-script start-dev\" \"npm run-script start\"",
        "heroku-postbuild": "npm install && npm run build"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "react-app"
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [">0.2%", "not dead", "not op_mini all"],
        "development": ["last 1 chrome version", "last 1 firefox version", "last 1 safari version"]
    },
    "homepage": "."
}
```

This is the **React.js file in charge of the payment**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import { CardElement, useStripe, useElements } from '@stripe/react-stripe-js';

// Bootstrap
import { Container, Row, Col, Button, Spinner, Form } from 'react-bootstrap';

export default function CheckoutForm(props) {
    const [ succeeded, setSucceeded ] = useState(false);
    const [ error, setError ] = useState(null);
    const [ processing, setProcessing ] = useState(false);
    const [ disabled, setDisabled ] = useState(true);
    const [ clientSecret, setClientSecret ] = useState('');
    const stripe = useStripe();
    const elements = useElements();
    useEffect(() => {
        console.log('inside use Effect');
        // Create PaymentIntent as soon as the page loads
        window
            .fetch('/create-payment-intent', {
                method: 'POST',
                headers: {
                    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
                },
                body: JSON.stringify({
                    items: {
                        drinks: props.drinksOrdered,
                        primerSegonCount: props.primerSegonCount,
                        dosPrimersCount: props.dosPrimersCount,
                        platPostresCount: props.platPostresCount
                    }
                })
            })
            .then((res) => {
                console.log(res);
                return res.json();
            })
            .then((data) => {
                console.log(data.clientSecret);
                console.log(data);
                setClientSecret(data.clientSecret);
            });
    }, []);

    const cardStyle = {
        base: {
            backgroundColor: 'white',
            color: 'grey',
            fontFamily: 'Montserrat, sans-serif',
            fontSmoothing: 'antialiased',
            fontSize: '16px',
            '::placeholder': {
                color: '#c6c6c6'
            }
        },
        invalid: {
            color: '#fa755a',
            iconColor: '#fa755a'
        },
        complete: {
            color: 'green',
            iconColor: 'green'
        }
    };

    const handleCardChange = async (event) => {
        // Listen for changes in the CardElement
        // and display any errors as the customer types their card details
        setDisabled(event.empty);
        setError(event.error ? event.error.message : '');
    };

    const handleSubmit = async (ev) => {
        ev.preventDefault();
        setProcessing(true);
        const payload = await stripe.confirmCardPayment(clientSecret, {
            payment_method: {
                card: elements.getElement(CardElement),
                billing_details: {
                    name: ev.target.name.value
                }
            }
        });

        // Handle Error
        if (payload.error) {
            setError(`Payment failed ${payload.error.message}`);
            setProcessing(false);
        } else if (payload.paymentIntent.status === 'succeeded') {
            // If payment succeeded, send eMail with details
            props.sendEmail();
            setSucceeded(true);
            setError(null);
            setTimeout(() => {
                window.location.replace('https://www.cateringroser.cat');
            }, 10000);
        }
    };
```

Thank you so much in advance.

Gerard

Answer (score 1):

Well, as I guessed, I had to figure this one out myself. :-)

If you go back to my original post, you will be able to see the code I had for my `server.js`, `package.json` and `CheckoutForm.jsx` files.

The `CheckoutForm.jsx` was ok. Below you can see the modified versions of the code for:

**server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const path = require('path');
const app = express();

const { resolve } = require('path');

const stripe = require('stripe')(process.env.STRIPE_SECRET_KEY);

app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'build')));
app.use(express.json());

// app.use(express.json());
const calculateOrderAmount = (items) => {
    let drinksTotal = 0;
    const { water, cola, colaZero, beer, lemonFanta, orangeFanta } = items.drinks;
    drinksTotal += water * 100;
    drinksTotal += (cola + colaZero + lemonFanta + orangeFanta) * 130;
    drinksTotal += beer * 150;

    let foodTotal = 0;
    foodTotal += items.primerSegonCount * 895;
    foodTotal += items.dosPrimersCount * 795;
    foodTotal += items.platPostresCount * 695;

    grandTotal = parseInt(drinksTotal + foodTotal);

    console.log(grandTotal);

    return grandTotal;
};

app.post('/create-payment-intent', async(req, res) => {
    const { items } = req.body;
    // Create a PaymentIntent with the order amount and currency
    const paymentIntent = await stripe.paymentIntents.create({
        amount: 100, //calculateOrderAmount(items),
        currency: 'eur'
    });
    res.send({
        clientSecret: paymentIntent.client_secret
    });
});

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'build', 'index.html'));
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

**package.json**

```
{
    "name": "my-app",
    "version": "1.0.0",
    "description": "take away restaurant app",
    "private": true,
    "engines": {
        "node": "12.x"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "^1.1.2",
        "@stripe/stripe-js": "^1.7.0",
        "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^4.2.4",
        "@testing-library/react": "^9.5.0",
        "@testing-library/user-event": "^7.2.1",
        "boostrap": "^2.0.0",
        "bootstrap": "^4.5.0",
        "concurrently": "^5.2.0",
        "cors": "^2.8.5",
        "dotenv": "^8.2.0",
        "emailjs-com": "^2.4.1",
        "express": "^4.17.1",
        "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
        "nodemon": "^2.0.4",
        "react": "^16.13.1",
        "react-bootstrap": "^1.0.1",
        "react-dom": "^16.13.1",
        "react-scripts": "3.4.1",
        "react-scroll": "^1.7.16",
        "react-stripe-checkout": "^2.6.3",
        "reactstrap": "^8.5.1",
        "stripe": "^8.67.0"
    },
    "scripts": {
        "start": "node server.js",
        "start-dev": "nodemon server.js",
        "build": "react-scripts build",
        "test": "react-scripts test",
        "eject": "react-scripts eject",
        "dev": "concurrently \"npm run-script start-dev\" \"npm run-script start\"",
        "heroku-postbuild": "npm install && npm run build"
    },
    "eslintConfig": {
        "extends": "react-app"
    },
    "browserslist": {
        "production": [">0.2%", "not dead", "not op_mini all"],
        "development": ["last 1 chrome version", "last 1 firefox version", "last 1 safari version"]
    }
}
```

I ended up using what I knew on server.js. I deleted everything I didn't understand and kept the original code.

One of the most important things was to understand what happens when you deploy an app using node/express (or at least I think I understand).

First, I thought I needed to deploy both the Front and Back End sepparately, and then link them somehow.

What (I think) I really needed to do was to serve the Front End files from the server. In my first attempts to deploy, I was really serving them from React directly, so all I was getting was an interactive painting, in which I could navigate, but hadn't the opportunity to communicate with the server (since it was not connected).

**What was the solution?**

1. Serve the `/build` folder and it's files as explained in [React's documentation on deployment](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/deployment/).
2. Remove the `"proxy": "http://localhost:5000"` from `package.json`. Also remove `"homepage":"xxx"` if you had so.
3. Add `"start": "node server.js"` to your `package.json`. You want to open your web through node.
4. I also added a `Procfile` as recommended in [Heroku's best practices for deployment with Node.js](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-nodejs#specifying-a-start-script). All I have in the file is the following code: `web: node server.js`.

It just makes sense now. I can accept payments and communicate with my server.

As a sidenote: I didn't delete any of the Stripe specific code in my server.js, since it might help other users using Stripe to handle payments.

Answer (score 0):

use secret key instead of public key in index.js in functions folder.